# Execute an action when transition from one specific state to another?

Tags: javascript, fsm, machina.js

Is there a way to execute an action when transitioning between specific states in Machina.js?

For example, say I have states "A, B, C".

I want to write a function like:

```
when("A", "C", function(){ console.log("Caught transition from A to C! Yay!"); }
```

This is in the same spirit as [Akka's FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) implementation. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. One just has to watch for `transition` event. See [API doc here](https://github.com/ifandelse/machina.js/wiki/FSM-events).

```
var fsm = new machina.Fsm({     
            initialState: 'A',      
            states: {
                "A":    {},
                "B" :   {},
                "C" :   {}
            }
        });


fsm.on('transition', function(transition){      
            console.log("[" + transition.fromState + "] -(" + transition.action  + ")-> [" + transition.toState + "]");
        });
```

Comment: Great - glad you found that! I was going to recommend listening for the transition event. Another option would be to check the priorState property on the FSM in the new state's entry action. I'll be sure and add some documentation on these sorts of use cases to the project's wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set something in the onExit of A, that you inspect in the onEnter of C?